# return value for timestamp difference

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I don't understand in what units does difference in timestamp returns answer.

when i select max(timestamp) and min(timestamp) from a colum, below are the values that i get.

```
max(timestamp)                    
2017-08-31 05:43:45 

min(timestamp)
2017-08-31 05:36:13
```

However below query return 732.

```
select max(timestamp) - min(timestamp) from <TABLE NAME>
```

however if put the timestamp inside time_to_sec() it gives current answer in seconds i.e. 452.So what am i missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do arithmetic with timestamps, it first converts them to numeric form `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS`. So that's `20170831054345 - 20170831053613` which is `732`.

If you want the result as a time, use the [`TIMEDIFF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) function.

```
select TIMEDIFF(max(timestamp), min(timestamp)) from <TABLE NAME>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's an interesting phenomenon and I'm curious to see if anybody comes up with a reason for why that's the case.

Generally, for calculating a timestamp difference, use [TIMESTAMPDIFF](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/date-and-time-functions/mysql-timestampdiff-function.php):

```
TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, min(timestamp), max(timestamp))
```